# Easy way to evaluate path-like expressions in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

If I have a JavaScript object such as:

```
var x = {foo: 42, bar: {fubar: true}}
```

then I can get the value `true` with `var flag = x.bar.fubar`. I'd like to be able to separate out and store the path `"bar.fubar"`, then evaluate it dynamically. Something like:

```
var paths = ["bar.fubar", ...];
...
var flag = evalPath( x, paths[0] );
```

Obviously I could write a simple parser and evaluator for a basic path expression grammar. But under DRY principles I wonder if there's already an existing way to do something like `evalPath` built-in to JavaScript, or a small library that would do the job? I also anticipate needing array indexes in the path expression in future.

**Update** Just to be clear, I'm not asking for code samples - my question is whether there's existing code (built-in or library) I can re-use. Thanks to the contributors below for suggestions of code samples anyway! Note that none of them handle the array index requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing a quick search, I came across [JSONPath](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/).  Haven't used it at all, but it looks like it might do what you want it to.

Example usage:

```
var x = {foo: 42, bar: {fubar: true}}
var res1 = jsonPath(x, "$.bar.fubar"); // Array containing fubar's value
```

Comment: Thanks cmptrgeekken, I also found the same package following a suggestion from Andy E. jsonPath seems to be working well so far

Answer (score 1):

Why not try something like

```
function evalPath(obj, path)
{
    var rtnValue = obj;

    // Split our path into an array we can iterate over
    var path = path.split(".");
    for (var i = 0, max=path.length; i < max; i++) 
    {
        // If setting current path to return value fails, set to null and break
        if (typeof (rtnValue = rtnValue[path[i]]) == "undefined")
        {
            rtnValue = null;
            break;
        }
    }

    // Return the final path value, or null if it failed
    return rtnValue;
}
```

Not tested, but it should work fairly well.  Like XPath, it will return null if it can't find what it's looking for.

Comment: Thanks Andy. I wasn't actually asking for code, I was asking whether there's a built-in way or a library to do this so I don't have to repeat (and write tests for!) code that's already out there.

Comment: @Ian Dickinson: fair enough.  I haven't ever come across such a thing.  I have searched for the same thing on several occasions, just because sometimes it would be easier to have a statement evaluate to null instead of throwing an error because a certain property didn't exist.  Kind of like using XPath instead of `documentElement.childNodes[0].childNodes[1].childNodes[47]`

Comment: Hmm, the XPath analogy was a good suggestion, thanks. I searched "JSON xpath" and came up with: http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/. Looks interesting, but I've not had chance to look at it in detail yet.

Comment: @Ian Dickinson: I never found that when I was searching :-) Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript provides `eval`, but I don't recommend it.

Comment: Indeed. I'm aware of `eval`, and it's not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this. I can't really think of a situation where it would be appropriate to store paths this way though.

```
function evalPath(obj, path) {
  var pathLevels = path.split('.');
  var result = obj;
  for (var i = 0; i < pathLevels.length; i++) {
    try {
      result = result[pathLevels[i]];
    }
    catch (e) {
      alert('Property not found:' + pathLevels[i]);
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

The `alert` is really only there for debugging purposes. You may want to return `null` or something.

Comment: Thanks ntownsend. I wasn't actually asking for code, I was asking whether there's a built-in way or a library to do this so I don't have to repeat (and write tests for!) code that's already out there.

Comment: By the way the use case is that I have a AJAX server serving up a fairly complex JSON data structure. The user can project out a variety of facets of the data structure into the UI; the path expressions will be stored as part of an extensible collection of declarative facet specifications. Representing how to map the data from the model to the view, essentially.

Comment: Ah. Then storing the paths would be appropriate. I've never seen any functionality like this in a library. You may be stuck with doing it yourself :)

Answer (score 0):

like

```
function locate(obj, path) {
    var p = path.split("."), a = p.shift();
    if(a in obj)
       return p.length ? locate(obj[a], p.join(".")) : obj[a];
     return undefined;
}

locate(x, "bar.fubar")
```

this works on the right only, of course

Comment: Thanks stereofrog. I wasn't actually asking for code, I was asking whether there's a built-in way or a library to do this so I don't have to repeat (and write tests for!) code that's already out there.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
evalPath = function(obj, path) {
  if (path[0] === "[") {
    return eval("obj" + path);
  } else {
    return eval("obj." + path);
  }
};
```

This has the advantage that it works for arbitrary strings:

evalPath([1,2,3], "[0]"); => 1

evalPath({a:{b:7}}, "a.b"); => 7

This, of course, only works if you really trust your input.